# How to Upload to SharePoint using a memory stream? Using COM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, streaming, memorystream

I am creating a method to `UploadDocument_FromStream()` method which has one parameter -- `Stream file`.

I am having trouble trying to keep my SharePoint connection open to allow me to upload my `Stream file` to SharePoint. I think the issue is due to the fact that I am executing a query then trying to upload to SharePoint.

Is this the best way to handle Uploading to SharePoint with a `MemoryStream`?

---

#### UploadDocument_FromStream()

```
public void UploadDocument_FromStream(Stream file)
    {
        using (var clientContext = OpenConnectionToSharePoint())
        {
            if (file == null) throw new Exception("Stream cannot be null");

            using (clientContext)
            {
                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, "/shared documents/test.pdf", file, true);
            }
     }
```

Also should note - that I am using `SharePoint.Client.dll` or COM approach.

Comment: did you check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609778/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-library-via-one-of-the-standard-webservices

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint CSOM API utilizes *internal query queue* to support [Request Batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx) via [`ClientRuntimeContext.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536388.aspx) method. But both [`File.OpenBinaryDirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect(v=office.14)) and [`File.SaveBinaryDirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.savebinarydirect(v=office.14).aspx) methods are executed *directly* and require internal queue to be empty. For that purpose you could utilize the following checking before invoking `File.SaveBinaryDirect` method:

```
if (ctx.HasPendingRequest)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The following example shows how to save a file stream into documents library

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);    
var fileUrl = Path.Combine(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fileName);

if (ctx.HasPendingRequest)
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, fileUrl, stream, true);
```